# how to remove edit, create delete access of Products

Tags: profile, permissions, permission-sets, customization, product

I tried removing edit create delete access of Products for a profile it is giving me following error

> Error: Invalid Data.
>
> Review all error messages below to correct your data.
> • Permission Read All Social Posts depends on permission(s): Read Social Posts
> • Permission View All Data depends on permission(s): Read Social Posts

Can any please help me resolve this, I got stuck with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be that there are other items checked for access on the Profile that you also need to change relating to the Read Social Posts permission. If you are trying to edit a profile remember that you need to look overall at the permissions on it as well as the specific changes required to make sure that there are no issues.

Check the System Permissions section for the Profile and remove View All Data if this is not appropriate for these users and then Object Settings>Social Posts and remove the 'Read All Social Posts' if not required or if Social Post access is required give the users 'Read Social Posts', see [image].

Comment: Thank you for the valuable solution. just wanted to know what is the purpose of Social post, what if it is not enabled or disabled? Please let me know

Comment: Social Post is used when you have integration to one or more social networks like Facebook, Twitter, etc. You can easily set the user profiles with no access to it if it is not required. If this has resolved your problem please mark the answer as accepted.